# How to validate a form based on an array of values

Tags: jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for the simplest way of validating a form, based on an array of values (this will be serial numbers so I have an array like this : abc123, xyz456, fghqwe, etc stored in a variable )

I have looked into some jQuery / Bootstrap validator plugins but was not able to come up with it.

So the code will check dynamically if a field = any of item in an array then success

I'm using wordpress + bootstrap

regards,
Craig

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Craig If you want to validate inputs according to your needs 
Jquery validate provides custom method support.

You can create your custom method like below

```
$.validator.addMethod("custom_function_name", function(value, element, param){
```

and call it from the rule's part of the validate method like below

```
rules : {
    property_name : custom_function_name
}
```

In your case you can use custom validation function like below(Sample Code)

**HTML :**

```
<form id="testForm">
    <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
    <input type="text" name="lastName"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**JQuery :**

```
$("#testForm").validate({
    rules : {
    firstName : {   required : true,
                    presentInList : true
    },
    lastName : {    required : true,
                    presentInList : true
    }
    },

    message : {
    firstName : { required : "Please enter"
    },
    lastName : { required : "Please enter"
    }
    },

     submitHandler: function (form) {
        console.log("Ok");
    }
});


var yourList = ["praksh", "Abhi"]

$.validator.addMethod("presentInList", function(value, element, param){
    if( $.inArray( value, yourList) != -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}, "not in list");
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/cncLa71b/

Comment: Thank you so much !! It works !! Just a quick question: am I trying to do it right? I have an array stored in php variable already accesible. abc, xyz, etc On the submit custom page (wordpress / woocommerce framework)  there will be this form which checks if the data is correct with the array. If so, the system will redirect to the new page and pass those submitted variable through  SESSION to be used in php WooCommerce framework

Comment: Craig Its not about right or wrong depending on the flow you are trying to implement solution changes. But as you have asked you may wan to store the values in key:val pair it will help you in identifying which array field to be matched with your input instead of searching through whole array(Assuming if your array is too long). ;)